# android Web service With broadcast reciever not work

Tags: android, broadcast

I'm trying to send data from my application SQLite database to an MySQL database in the server side through a POST request when the device connection is available.
I have the connectivity change BroadcastReceiver as an inner class in my Activity, but it doesn't work and never gets triggered.

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public static final String url ="http://path/Insert.php";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        boolean isConnected = wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting() ||
                mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        if (isConnected) {

        Sql = new SqlCommands(MainActivity.this);
        final Cursor c = Sql.GetData();
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {

                try{
                    DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> List = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    List.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Latt", c.getString(1)));
                    List.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Lang", c.getString(2)));
                    List.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Date", c.getString(3)));
                    List.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Time", c.getString(4)));

                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(List, "UTF-8"));
                    HttpResponse response = defaultClient.execute(post);
                    StatusLine line = response.getStatusLine();
                    if (line.getStatusCode()==HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                    {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                        String feedback = out.toString();
                        Log.i("the response", feedback);
                    }
                    }       
                 catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.i("Exception",e.toString());
                }

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        Sql.close();

        //}
        }
     else {
            Log.d("Network Available ", "NO");
        }
    }}}
```

and here the registration on the manifest file:

```
  <receiver android:name="com.example.demo_gps.MainActivity$NetworkChangeReceiver"  >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

On the application tag, please tell me where is the problem, thanks in advance.

Here's the database code:

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           while(MainActivity.this.gotLocation() == false){
               //do nothing, just wait
       }

                     //once done return true
            try {

                    Sql = new SqlCommands(MainActivity.this);
                    Sql.AddEntry(String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(longitude), D, T);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } });                                   

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.i("Exception",e.toString());
            }

    return true;    

    }
}
```

Comment: 'from a SQLite database'. Where is that database resided?

Comment: @greenapps I will add it to the post

Comment: You did not answer my question though. You will find errors in your logcat. One thing why this can not work is because you forgot the INTERNET permission in manifest.

Comment: @greenapps No the INTERNET permission is exist and added

Comment: Can you post your whole MainActivity code?

Comment: post your log, there must be errors in it. Filter by error. Probably security exception but could be other exception.  What api are you running on, is it 23 ?